# Why is my Google App Engine run options missing in eclipse..?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, plugins

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and installed Eclipse 3.7 Indigo..
I then installed the Google plugin for Eclipse..

It adds the blue Google button on the toolbar just fine, but there is no options in the "Run as" menu..

What went wrong and how do I fix it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around a bit I found a solution..

The problem was that the Launch command group was disabled.. I went to Window > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability... and enabled the Launch group..

Now I can easily run my Project from the toolbar.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Things get added to the "Run as..." menu as they are used.

Google App Engine plugin in eclipse uses the "Web Application" run configuration.

So basically, to get it to start showing up there....

1. Right click on your project folder in the project explorer
2. Click on "Run As..." in the context menu
3. If you don't see "Web Application" in the context menu, just hit other/etc and look for it.
4. Once you find the "Web Application" launch configuration and you run it, it should show up in your "Run As..." menu going forward.

If this doesn't help you out then comment and I'll post screen shots later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks.. That at least gave me a way to run my project, but I found out that it was just the Launch command group that was disabled..